# Шум в Reflection probe при использовании Emissive Unity 5.3.6

Tags: unity3d, рефлексия, шейдеры

Я разрабатываю игру Russian Rider Online и хочу улучшить качество графики. В данный момент работаю над сценой с гаражом в котором стоит выбранная машина. Запекаю освещение и Reflection probe с параметром HDR, освещаю сцену при помощи геометрии, на которой "висит" Standart shader с параметром emissive. При таком подходе в Reflection probe появляется шум, а вот если осветить сцену при помощи area light то шума нет. Что я делаю не так? Откуда этот шум?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]